# Comparing rows in a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame suppose say `df`.

```
import pandas as pd

data_dic = {
    "a": [0,0,1,2],
    "b": [0,3,4,5],
    "c": [6,7,8,9]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dic)
```

It will look like:

```
   a  b  c
0  0  0  6
1  0  3  7
2  1  4  8
3  2  5  9
```

Now i want to compare `row[0]` with `row[1]` for column a and post the greater value or some remark in a new column, say `d`.

I have tried using:

```
for i in range(len(df):
   if (df.iloc[a][i] > df.iloc[a][i+1]):
      df[d] = "Post the greater number"
```

I am getting an error:

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you when i is at the last index, i+1 will be out of bounds.

I think you might want to write:

```
for i in range(len(df) - 1):
  if (df.iloc[a][i] > df.iloc[a][i+1]):
    df[d] = "Post the greater number"
```

Comment: Thanks it works now but now I am facing another issue as it is updating the same value in all rows for new column d. I have tried to correct this by
``` 
df[d][i] = "Post the greater number" 
````
but it is still throwing error and says Keyerror "d"